# We've created a new website, but the old URLs should continue to work because people have bookmarked them

Tags: apache, .htaccess

The only problem is

The old urls are something like this www.example.com/?pt#!/2/1270/something-etc-etc/

and we want to redirect them,  but we need to pass the something-etc-etc to the new url.
Something like this new.example.com/old/ plus(something-etc-etc)

I've been trying so many ways that I'm already lost

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ([:alnum:]-)+?[:alnum:]/$
RedirectMatch www.example.com/ http://new.example.com/old/

I was hoping that this regex will return only the ending part, but instead, it returns ?pt#!/2/1270/something-etc-etc/

Comment: Keep in mind that anything after the hash mark in the URL won't be sent to the server, so if you need that information to perform the redirect you have no choice but to do the work client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use the Apache mod_rewrite module as described in the [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/). A bit of a heavy read if you haven't used mod_rewrite before, but well well worth learning. Lots of examples to make things concrete, too.